# What is the view of Vedanta on attaining Realization in other than human form; as plant, animal, fish etc.?

Tags: animals, enlightenment

Gita
Upanishads
Hindu texts on philosophy

Comment: No, you can only attain realization of God/Brahman, by being a human. This is why a human birth is given so much importance in hunduism. Birth in a human body is considered superior because of its intelligence and because of its power to discriminate (of what's right and wrong). A human body can only meditate on Brahman/God and not birds, beasts and aquatic creatures.